# DateTime.TryParseExact C# valid format and parsing

Tags: c#, datetime

Came across with a problem of pasing format.

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateOn))
{
     return false;
}
else if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(timeString, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeOn))
{
     return false;
}

return SaveWorkshop(id, name, dateOn, timeOn, capacity, description, duration, isCancelled);
```

Using Bootstrap Datetimepicker, it does takes a strings from textboxes in format

> dateString = 11/28/2015 and timeString = 6:46 AM

But in the result I do have false and is parsing default date. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your `timeString`, you need to use `h` instead of `hh` specifier.

[`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) is needs a [leading zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero) for single digits like `06`. You need to use [`h` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hSpecifier) instead.

That's why your second `DateTime.TryParseExact` returns `false` and `timeOn` will be it's default value.

Comment: "hh" is not for 24-hour time.  The link you provided actually says that.  It is for zero-padded 12-hour time.  "h" is for non-zero-padded 12-hour time, "H" is for non-zero-padded 24-hour time and "HH" is for zero-padded 24-hour time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Looks like you are the first person who notice my mistake :) Thank you very much. I edited.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, "hh" requires a two-digit hour, which you don't have.  Use "h" for non-zero-padded values.

Answer (score 0):

Further, your parsing of the time returns today's date at Midnight added the TimeSpan from parsing `timeString`.

Thus, to cut off today's date, do something like this:

```
// snip ..
DateTime datetimeOn = dateOn.Add(timeOn.TimeOfDay);
return SaveWorkshop(id, name, datetimeOn, capacity, description, duration, isCancelled);
```

or, of course, modify `SaveWorkshop` to create `datetimeOn` internally.

**Edit**

Also, you could parse in one go:

```
DateTime datetimeOn;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString + timeString, "MM/dd/yyyyh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeOn);
```

Comment: I was using this way before, but on grid-view I want to separate time and date columns.

Comment: OK, but couldn't you just concatenate these before parsing? See edit.